# Linq C# Check two array if second array one or more of the value match with first array

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, linq

I have two array `array_A` and `array_B`, `array_A` is from the DB, `array_B` is user selected value from front-end. So, I have to match and filter between two array, if `array_A` contain one or more value from `array_B`, then this consider true, will take the db data. I using **MongoDB**. Below is my code:

```
var builder = Builders<Order>.Filter;
var filter = FilterDefinition<Order>.Empty;

//db data value may look like this
//db data 1) => selectedItems:["item_B","item_A","item_S"]
//db data 2) => selectedItems:["item_S","item_Z"]
//db data 3) => selectedItems:["item_C","item_D"]

//frontend value
string[] selectedItems = ["item_A","item_Z"];

filter = filter & builder.Where(c => c.selectedItems.Any(x => selectedItems.Contains(x)));
```

The result should take the `data 1` and `data 2`, because `data 3` no have value match the frontend value, correct me if I wrong.

Comment: What are you using linq with? MongoDb? CosmonDb? What error do get to see?

Comment: @bit using mongodb, no error, just doesn't match my expected result

Comment: Just `Intersect` two arrays and it will give you the expected output.

Comment: Your query seems to be correct. You might want to debug for case sensitivity or something.. Try adding a breakpoint inside the Any() and Where()

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya - That doesn't sound like what the OP needs.

Comment: What syntax is `["item_A","item_Z"];`?

Comment: @ImHappy - Can you please correct your code and make it clear what data is from the DB and what is the the selected item data? Also remove the superfluous code. `Builders<Order>.Filter` and `FilterDefinition<Order>.Empty` are not relevant as far as I can tell. If they are, then please provide the full definition of your code.

Comment: Mongo DB by default is case sensitive, as user @bit mentioned please check for this, your code is fine. Assuming `c.selectedItems` is an array of type string inside the `Order` class